# почему ссылка съезжает

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_script.css">
        <title>о нас</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <head>
        <section>
            <h1 class="auu">О НАС</h1>
            <a class="back" href="menu.html"><h3>назад</h3></a>
        </section>
        <hr>
        </head>
        <main>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus blanditiis tenetur tempore fugiat incidunt ducimus aliquam eaque natus molestias eos distinctio nostrum et, amet, labore, recusandae eum saepe! Mollitia, doloribus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero iste commodi ipsa, atque repudiandae dolorem ex voluptate amet vel deleniti nam rerum. Obcaecati doloremque animi quod earum deleniti perferendis atque? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium labore modi temporibus sint accusamus tenetur soluta error dignissimos odio exercitationem velit reiciendis inventore molestias ipsum culpa ullam, possimus facilis pariatur.</p>
            <a href="#" class="topbutton"><h5>наверх</h5></a>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
a {
font-size: xx-large;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

если вертикально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но если горизонтально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показанный вами код не позволяет воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Даже после правки новый код всё ещё не позволяет воспроизвести проблему

Comment: а что еще нужно добавить?

Comment: То, что требуется для того, чтобы увидеть описанную вами проблему. Сейчас результат отображения показанного вами кода даже отдалённо не напоминает то, что изображено на скриншотах

Comment: ссылка 'назад' съезжает вниз если телефон вертикально

Comment: В показанном вами коде ссылка «назад» находится внизу вообще всегда, даже на горизонтальных компьютерах — просто потому, что тег `<h1>` является блочным на всю ширину и у ссылки «назад» нет абсолютно никаких причин быть не внизу или располагаться справа. Более того, буквы «назад» написаны белым текстом на белом фоне, так что ссылка тут вообще полностью невидимая

Comment: @izen02, мне кажется вам стоит изменить вторую пару тегов head на header